# Simple cURL not returning anything

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to perform a cURL with no luck. If I visit the url:

http://webgis.dor.wa.gov/webapi/addressrates.aspx?output=xml&addr=416+Sid+Snyder+Ave+SW&city=Olympia&zip=98504

then I can see an XML document.

However, using PHP 5.6, nothing is returned.  In particular, I'm using the following code:

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init("http://webgis.dor.wa.gov/webapi/addressrates.aspx?output=xml&addr=416+Sid+Snyder+Ave+SW&city=Olympia&zip=98504");

  curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
  ));
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 if(!$result)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "Info: ";
print_r($info);
echo "Result: ";
var_dump($result);
```

with a result of:

```
 Info: array(26) { 
["url"]=> string(110) "http://webgis.dor.wa.gov/webapi/addressrates.aspx?output=xml&addr=416+Sid+Snyder+Ave+SW&city=Olympia&zip=98504" ["content_type"]=> string(8) "text/xml" 
["http_code"]=> int(200) 
["header_size"]=> int(236) 
["request_size"]=> int(141) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0.654618) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.004215) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0.064022) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.064091) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(369) 
["speed_download"]=> float(369) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(369) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.654568) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" 
["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "198.105.130.18" 
["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
["primary_port"]=> int(80) 
["local_ip"]=> string(14) "162.244.253.84"
 ["local_port"]=> int(54442) }

 Result: string(369) ""
```

Comment: this link is a `asp.net` link , and api is `soap api` , try how to call `soap api` from php

Comment: You are getting the response as an array, what else you want?

Comment: Sorry...it was actually a var_dump originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://webgis.dor.wa.gov/webapi/addressrates.aspx?output=xml&addr=416%20Sid%20Snyder%20Ave%20SW&city=Olympia&zip=98504",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {

  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;

} else {

  echo $response;

 // convert it to array if you want
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $json = json_encode($xml);
 $arr = json_decode($json,true);
 print '<pre>';
 print_r($arr);
 print '</pre>';

}
```

Comment: @Eric no problem, here on SO everyone is not a genius :P. Best of luck..:)

Answer (score 0):

Always check if curl request succeeded. Don't assume that it was successful.

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```